# Flash[:notice] doesn't show properly for automatic validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm using Rails 2.3.4/Ruby 1.9.1 for my application. In the view I have this to show error messages:

```
<%= content_tag('div', flash[:notice], :class => 'flash notice') if flash[:notice] %>
```

it works fine if I assign it manually from the controller such as:

```
flash[:notice] = "User Name can only contain letters, number - or _"
```

But for the automatic validation in the model such as:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name
```

the error messages don't show! although the form doesn't submit which what should happen but I don't see the error messages.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless this has changed very recently in rails, flash[:notice] is never populated by model validations.  To display errors from a validation in the view, you would use the [error_messages_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper.html#M001694) method.